Best way to solve $\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x-1}+1}$
I know there isn't a "best" way to solve an integral, rather I am looking for an alternative method than the one I used which was rather tedious. My attempt is below:
$$I=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x-1}+1}\,\, \mathrm{d}x$$
Let $x=u^2\implies \, \mathrm{d}x=2u\,\, \mathrm{d}u$
$$\begin{align*}
I&=2\int\frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2-1}+u+1}\,\, \mathrm{d}u \\
&=2\int\frac{u\sqrt{u^2-1}-u^2-u}{u^2-1-(u+1)^2}\,\, \mathrm{d}u\\
&=2\int\frac{u\sqrt{u^2-1}-u^2-u}{-2u-2}\,\, \mathrm{d}u\\
&=\int\frac{u^2+u-u\sqrt{u^2-1}}{u+1}\,\, \mathrm{d}u\\
&=\int\frac{u^2}{u+1}\,\, \mathrm{d}u+\int\frac{u}{u+1}\,\, \mathrm{d}u-\int\frac{u\sqrt{u^2-1}}{u+1}\,\, \mathrm{d}u \\
&=I_1+I_2-I_3 \tag{$\ast$}
\end{align*}$$
Now computing each integral $I_n$ separately:
$$\begin{align*}
I_1&=\int\frac{u^2}{u+1}\,\, \mathrm{d}u\\
&=\frac{u^2}{2}-u+\ln|{u+1}|\\
I_2&=\int\frac{u}{u+1}\,\, \mathrm{d}u\\
&=u-\ln|u+1|
\end{align*}$$
$I_3$ requires more work, I split it into $R_1$ and $R_2$
$$\begin{align*}
I_3&=\int\frac{u\sqrt{u^2-1}}{u+1}\,\, \mathrm{d}u\\
&=\int\sqrt{u^2-1}\,\, \mathrm{d}u-\int\frac{\sqrt{u^2-1}}{u+1}\,\, \mathrm{d}u\\
&=R_1-R_2
\end{align*}$$
Continuing with $R_1$:
$$R_1=\int\sqrt{u^2-1}\,\, \mathrm{d}u$$
Let $u=\sec\theta\implies \, \mathrm{d}u=\tan\theta\cdot\sec\theta\,\, \mathrm{d} \theta$.
$$\begin{align*}
R_1
&=\int\sqrt{\sec^2\theta-1}\tan\theta\cdot\sec\theta\,\, \mathrm{d} \theta\\
&=\int\tan^2\theta\sec\theta\,\, \mathrm{d} \theta\\
&=\int(\sec^2\theta-1)\sec\theta\,\, \mathrm{d} \theta\\
&=\int\sec^3\theta\,\, \mathrm{d} \theta-\int\sec\theta\,\, \mathrm{d} \theta\\
R_1&=\frac{u\sqrt{u^2-1}}{2}-\frac{\ln(\sqrt{u^2-1}+u)}{2}
\end{align*}$$
Now $R_2$:
$$R_2=\int\frac{\sqrt{u^2-1}}{u+1}\,\, \mathrm{d}u$$
Let $u=\sec\theta\implies \, \mathrm{d}u=\sec\theta\tan\theta\, \, \mathrm{d} \theta$.
$$\begin{align*}
R_2&=\int\frac{\sec\theta\tan\theta\sqrt{\sec^2\theta-1}}{\sec\theta+1}\, \mathrm{d} \theta\\
&=\int\frac{\sec\theta\tan^2\theta}{\sec\theta+1}\, \mathrm{d} \theta\\
&=\int(1-\cos\theta)(\sec^2\theta)\,\, \mathrm{d} \theta\\
&=\int\sec^2\theta\,\, \mathrm{d} \theta-\int\cos\theta\sec^2\theta\,\, \mathrm{d} \theta\\
&=\tan\theta-\ln(\tan\theta+\sec\theta)\\
R_2&=\sqrt{u^2-1}-\ln(\sqrt{u^2-1}+u)
\end{align*}$$
Therefore $$I_3=\frac{u\sqrt{u^2-1}}{2}-\frac{\ln(\sqrt{u^2-1}+u)}{2}+\sqrt{u^2-1}-\ln(\sqrt{u^2-1}+u)$$
Combining this with $(\ast)$ we can finally simplify the solution:
$$\begin{align*}
I&=\frac{u^2}{2}-\require{cancel}\cancel{u}+\cancel{\ln|u+1|}+\cancel{u}-\cancel{\ln|u+1|}-\frac{u\sqrt{u^2-1}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\ln(\sqrt{u^2-1}+u)+\sqrt{u^2-1} \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left( x-\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x-1}-\ln(\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{x})+2\sqrt{x-1} \right) \\
&=\boxed{\frac{1}{2}\left( x-\sqrt{x-1}(\sqrt{x}-2)-\ln(\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{x}) \right)+C}
\end{align*}$$
While this method arrives at (I believe) the correct result it is very tedious and provides many opportunities for mistakes. I would appreciate any ideas on alternative ways to solve this integral.

After $x=u^2$, try an Euler substitution. No guarantee that it will involve less work, however.

Not that it will reduce the work, but it is interesting that multiplying by $\frac{\sqrt x-\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt x-\sqrt{x-1}}$ gives a highly similar denominator to the original.

I attempted $x=\sec^2t$, but putting everything in terms of sines and cosines was still pretty ugly.  I don't know if anything good comes of writing $1$ as $\sqrt x^2-\sqrt{x-1}^2$ and factoring.  Might be worth a try.

nice question  ........ +1

If you make the substitution $u = \sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x-1}+1$, then $x = \frac{u^4 - 4u^3 + 8u^2 - 8u + 4}{4(u - 1)^2}$.  The algebra to find that is a bit tedious, though.

For $I_3$, a shorter method(without any substitution) is to rationalize the numerator, then split it into $3$ integrals.

Let $t^2=x-1$, then
$$
\begin{aligned}\int \frac{d x}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x-1}+1} 
= & \int \frac{2 t d t}{\sqrt{t^2+1}+t+1} \\
= & \int \frac{2 t\left(t+1-\sqrt{t^2+1}\right)}{(t+1)^2-\left(t^2+1\right)} d t \\
= & \int\left(t+1-\sqrt{t^2+1}\right) d t \\
= & \frac{t^2}{2}+t-\frac{1}{2}\left(t \sqrt{t^2+1}+\ln \left(\sqrt{t^2+1}+t\right)\right)+C \\
= & \frac{x-1}{2}+\sqrt{x-1}-\frac{1}{2}[x \sqrt{x-1}+\ln (\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x-1})]+C
\end{aligned}
$$
Wish it helps.

It helps. easy and enough

Substitute $x=\cosh^2t$
\begin{align}
 & \int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x-1}+1}dx\\
= & \int\frac{\sinh2t}{e^t+1}dt
=\frac12 \int (1-e^{-t})(e^t+ e^{-t})dt\\
=&\ \frac12\left(\frac12e^{-2t}+e^t-e^{-t}-t\right)+C
\end{align}
Then, back-substitute with $e^t=\sqrt x+\sqrt{x-1}$.

One way that comes to mind is to multiply by a sort of radical conjugate a couple of times until the denominator is less unpleasant. Note that
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\sqrt x + \sqrt{x-1} + 1}
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt x + \sqrt{x-1} + 1} \cdot \frac{-\sqrt x - \sqrt{x-1} + 1}{-\sqrt x - \sqrt{x-1} + 1}\\
&= \frac{-\sqrt x - \sqrt{x-1} + 1}{2-2 x - 2 \sqrt{x - 1} \sqrt x}\\
&= \frac{-\sqrt x - \sqrt{x-1} + 1}{2-2 x - 2 \sqrt{x - 1} \sqrt x} \cdot \frac{2-2 x + 2 \sqrt{x - 1} \sqrt x}{2-2 x+ 2 \sqrt{x - 1} \sqrt x} \\
&= \frac{-2 x + 2 \sqrt{x - 1} \sqrt{x} - 2 \sqrt{x - 1} + 2}{4-4x}\\
&= \frac 12 \cdot \frac{-  x +  \sqrt{x - 1} \sqrt{x} -   \sqrt{x - 1} + 1}{1- x}
\end{align*}$$
You could then use linearity from here, and each integral looks like it'd be quite straightforward.

The hardest part at the end is integrating the second term, $\sqrt \frac{x}{1-x}.$ But there are a couple of methods for how to do this here

$$\begin{align*}
& \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt x + \sqrt{x-1} + 1} \\
&= \int \frac{2t}{t + \sqrt{t^2-1} + 1} \, dt & x=t^2 \\
&= \int \frac{2\sec^2u\tan u}{1+\sec u+\tan u} \, du & t=\sec u \\
&= \int \frac{v^3-v^2+v-1}{2v^3} \, dv & v=\sec u+\tan u
\end{align*}$$
The first two substitutions are natural. In the last step, we are utilizing
$$u=\sec\theta+\tan\theta=\frac{1+\tan\frac\theta2}{1-\tan\frac\theta2}=\tan\left(\frac\theta2+\frac\pi4\right),$$
a cousin to the tangent half-angle substitution.

Let $x = \cosh^2 t$ so that $\mathrm{d}x = 2\cosh t \sinh t\,\mathrm{d}t$, so
$$ 
\begin{aligned}
\int \! \frac{1}{\sqrt{x\phantom{1}\!\!}+\sqrt{x-1}+1} \, \mathrm{d}x
&= \int \! \frac{2\cosh t \sinh t}{\cosh t + \sinh t + 1} \, \mathrm{d}t \\[-2pt]
&= \frac12 \int \frac{e^{2t} - e^{-2t}}{e^t + 1} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \frac12 \int \bigl( e^t - 1 + e^{-t} - e^{-2t} \bigr) \, \mathrm{d}t \\[4pt]
&= \tfrac12 \bigl( e^t - t - e^{-t} + \tfrac12 e^{-2t} \bigr) + C
\end{aligned}
$$
With $\sqrt{x} = \cosh t$, the antiderivative is
$$ 
\begin{aligned}
\int \! \frac{1}{\sqrt{x\phantom{1}\!\!}+\sqrt{x-1}+1} \, \mathrm{d}x
&= \tfrac12 \bigl(e^t - e^{-t}\bigr) + \tfrac14 e^{-2t} - \tfrac12 t + C \\[-4pt]
&= \sqrt{x-1\,} + \tfrac14 \bigl(\sqrt{x\phantom{1}\!\!} - \sqrt{x-1\,}\bigr)^2 - \tfrac12 \cosh^{-1}\!\!\sqrt{x\phantom{1}\!\!} + C \\[6pt] 
&= \sqrt{x-1\,} + \tfrac14(2x - 1) - \tfrac12 \sqrt{x\phantom{1}\!\!} \sqrt{x-1\,} - \tfrac12 \ln\bigl(\sqrt{x\phantom{1}\!\!} + \sqrt{x-1\,} \bigr) + C,
\end{aligned}
$$
which differs from your final answer by a constant.

Yes, it looks like another person wrote down essentially the same answer as me without explaining the back substitution in as much detail. This happens sometimes when it takes time to type out formulas, and two people have a similar idea. :-)

As @Dan suggested in comments
$$u = \sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x-1}+1 \implies x=\frac{\left(u^2-2 u+2\right)^2}{4 (u-1)^2}$$ $$\implies dx=\frac{(u-2) u \left(u^2-2 u+2\right)}{2 (u-1)^3}$$
$$\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x-1}+1}=\int \frac{(u-2) \left(u^2-2 u+2\right)}{2 (u-1)^3}\,du$$ Using partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac{(u-2) \left(u^2-2 u+2\right)}{2 (u-1)^3}=-\frac{1}{2 (u-1)}+\frac{1}{2 (u-1)^2}-\frac{1}{2
   (u-1)^3}+\frac{1}{2}$$ which is not difficult.

Substitute $x=\sec^2\theta$:
$$\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x-1}+1}$$
$$=2\int\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos^3\theta(\sec\theta+\tan\theta+1)}\mathrm d\theta$$
$$=2\int\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos^2\theta(1+\sin\theta+\cos\theta)}\mathrm d\theta$$
$$=2\int\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos^2\theta}\times\frac{\sin\theta+\cos\theta-1}{\sin2\theta}\mathrm d\theta$$
$$=\int\frac{\sin\theta+\cos\theta-1}{\cos^3\theta}\mathrm d\theta$$
$$=\int\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos^3\theta}\mathrm d\theta+\int\sec^2\theta\mathrm d\theta-\int\sec^3\theta\mathrm d\theta$$
You can take it from here.
